# Can I pass a function closure (with my parameters) as Firebase's set() method 'oncomplete' argument?

Tags: firebase

I want to do further processing depending on the success or failure of the set() method, but I need the context of some objects at the time I call the set() method. Otherwise my objects will be out of scope when the oncomplete function is called unless I put them in global - which I don't really want to do.

Here is an example:

```
    function oncomplete_AddTran(tran,client,appt,balance){
      /* if named argument 'balance' exists it is safe to assume
         Firebase has not 'stepped on' the arguments with it's single
         Error object or null */
      if(balance typeof object) console.log("my parameters made it here");
    }
    function addTran(tran, client, appt, balance) {
    var TRANS_LOCATION = 'https://xxx.firebaseIO.com/testing/transactions';
    var tranListRef = new Firebase(TRANS_LOCATION);
    var oncomplete = function() {
         oncomplete_AddTran(tran, client, appt, balance); };
    var tranref = tranListRef.child(tran.name).set(tran.literal, oncomplete);
    }
```

Comment: can you show an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3 : yes, in just a few minutes please find my question updated with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I am too impatient waiting for the confirmation I was looking for and decided to test myself. Here is the code I used (that works for my purpose):

```
    function oncomplete_AddTran(tran,client,appt,balance){
      console.log("arguments passed:" + arguments.length);
      // firebase original arguments :: arguments.callee.caller.arguments
      var fbargs = arguments.callee.caller.arguments; 
    }
    function addTran(tran, client, appt, balance) {
      var TRANS_LOCATION = "https://xxx.firebaseIO.com/testing/transactions";
      var tranListRef = new Firebase(TRANS_LOCATION);
      var oncomplete = function() { 
                         oncomplete_AddTran(tran, client, appt, balance); };
      var tranref = tranListRef.child(tran.name).set(tran.literal, oncomplete);
    }
    function main() {
      var tran = {}; tran.name = "test1"; tran.literal = { tran: "tran" };
      var client = {}; client.literal = { client: "client" };
      var appt = {}; appt.literal = { appt:"appt" };
      var balance = {}; balance.literal = { balance:"balance" };
      addTran(tran,client,appt,balance);
    }
```

The arguments were passed as expected but I still don't know how Firebase's set() method will pass the error object to the callback (in the event of an error) because I haven't tried reproducing an error and don't really know if I can.

The default null, and another (undefined) that is supposed to be passed when there is no error is not found in arguments.callee.caller.arguments (see callback function in example above). I am not sure that what I am doing is good practice - seems a bit hacky to me so I won't accept this answer to the question (yet).

Comment: I'm hoping a Firebase expert can comment on this answer, provide another answer, or upvote this answer soon :)

Comment: It has been several months and I had hoped for any alternate answers or suggestions or corrections. The answer I offered below worked well for me so I will accept it in hopes others might find it useful. I'm not a big fan of auto-answered questions on stackoverflow except in cases where there are no alternative solutions offered and the author has solved his or her own problem out of necessity. No flames please ;)